# ASP.NET MVC - How to stop processing request from controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, controller

I have something like that

```
public abstract class MyController : Controller
{
    public MyController()
    {
        // do some magic here
    }

    protected override void Initialize(RequestContext requestContext)
    {
        base.Initialize(requestContext);

        if (someMagicWentWrong)
        {
            requestContext.HttpContext.Response.Redirect("http://example.com/");
        }
    }
}
```

It works almost like I need. If I access web page and some magic goes wrong I get HTTP 302 response. BUT there is one thing that also happens - it continues in processing original request.

How can I achieve to stop processing request? If some magic goes wrong, just redirect and stop doing anything else?

I tried to add "Response.End" after Redirect but it does not work.

Comment: redirecting while controller initializing is not right. Can you explain why you need to do this? Why you can not use OnActionExecuting method for this?

Comment: I need to prevent users from accessing/calling actions from controllers which inherit MyController. I want to do it as soon as possible.

Comment: Now I tried OnActionExecuting and it works like a charm. I did not know about it. Thanks